# getting Error : could not be set to a 'System.Guid' value must be set a property non-null value of type 'System.String'.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am create small demo for user registration using web api mvc c#.i am register Succeeded for user.now i am go for the edit user so for the edit i want to get the user information b userid. click on edit i am getting like this error :

> The 'userid' property on 'UserJobs' could not be set to a 'System.Guid' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'

any one know how can i resolved this error.

this is my class UserJobs :

```
[Table("UserJobs")]
public class UserJobs
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }       
    public string userid { get; set; }
}
```

this is my method :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetSupportById")]        
public ActionResult GetSupportById(string id)
{
    try
    {
        var UsersContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var Team = UsersContext.Users.Find(id);

        string uid = Team.Id;

        var re = db.UserJobs.Where(t => t.userid == uid).ToList(); // getting here error.

        return Json(new { data = Details });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {               
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems `Team.Id` is null, could you verify?

Comment: yes it is not null is always getting id.

Comment: what's the actual value of `uid`?

Comment: What is the data type in the table `UserJobs` for `userId` column?

Comment: Could you update the question with the User class definition

Comment: yes i m replace string to guid data type for userid